# Get paginated result in Mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am playing with some large amount of data and to query that data I am using mongodb aggregation framework. Here is a sample data:

```
{
   "id": "1"
   "name":"abc"
},
{
   "id": "2"
   "name":"abc"
},
{
   "id": "3"
   "name":"abc"
},
...,
{
   "id": "100"
   "name":"abc"
}
```

So what I am doing is 10 results at a time so for that I set the $limit to 10. But what if I want 10 result after *id*:10 i.e. 10 results after the object with id 10. So it should return

```
{
   "id": "11"
   "name":"abc"
},
{
   "id": "12"
   "name":"abc"
},
{
   "id": "13"
   "name":"abc"
},
...(And So on till id:20)
```

Is there any way to do this kind of aggregation query? Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While requesting for results, pass pageSize and pageNumber in your request.

```
db.your_collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            // your query
        }
    },
    {
        "$skip": (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize
    },
    {
        "$limit": pageSize
    }
])
```

Or you can use:

```
db.your_collection.find({/*your query*/}).skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).limit(pageSize)
```